# Recovery that does not use touch?

Tags: recovery-mode, unrooting, htc-one-m8

I have an HTC M8 One.  The digitiser has failed.  HTC won't accept the repair since I have rooted the phone.  I'd like to unroot and return to stock but all of the recoveries I have found, or, the installers for stock ROMs, use the touch screen somewhere.

Does anyone know of a combination of recovery and stock ROM install that I can use?

Answer (score 0):

ClockworkMod Recovery doesn't use touch interface. If you can flash stock ROM with it.. But you may have problem getting rid of CWM after flashing the ROM. It might be possible - some ROM's do a reflash of recovery partition before every reboot. You can try letting the battery run low to the point where the system shuts down automatically.

Comment: CWM even has "temporary versions", which are not "really installed". You'd act as if installing them, but they are not written to permanent storage – but only loaded to memory and run; after the next boot, they're gone again (comparable to a "temp root"). Not sure if such a version exists for this device, though.

Comment: Yes, these can be sideloaded via fastboot. Totally forgot about them :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to get your phone back to the way it was when you got it, I recommend flashing an RUU instead. It reverts your recovery and bootloader too. You won't even need a custom recovery to do this.

There are many RUUs available, like [this one for the GSM HTC One GPE](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2708589). Just make sure you download the correct package for your device and follow all  and instructions provided.

*At the end of the process, you can even re-lock your bootloader security* by running `fastboot oem lock` from a connected computer, while on your phone's fastboot screen **([Bootloader] > Fastboot)**.

*Note: Be especially careful when flashing an RUU because, while it reverts your recovery, bootloader, and system, it can possibly corrupt those files and potentially render your phone a brick.